# Difference in my and wolfram's integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Calculate 
$$\int \frac{\sin ^3(x)+1}{\cos (x)+1} \, dx$$

Let $$u = \tan(x/2)$$ 
    $\int \frac{\sin ^3(x)+1}{\cos (x)+1} \, dx = \int \frac{2\left(\frac{8u^3}{(u^2+1)^3}+1 \right)}{(u^2+1)\left( \frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1} + 1 \right)} \, du = \int \frac{8u^3}{(u^2+1)^3 } + 1 \, du$
    $$ s := u^2 \wedge ds = 2u \, du $$
    $ u + \int \frac{8su}{(s+1)^3 } (2u)^{-1} \, ds = u + 4\int \frac{s}{(s+1)^3 }  \, ds = $
    $ u + 4\int \frac{1}{(s+1)^2 } - \frac{1}{(s+1)^3 }  \, ds =  u + 4\left(\frac{-1}{s+1} +\frac{1}{2(s+1)^2} \right) + C =$ 
    $ u + 4\left(\frac{-1}{u^2+1} +\frac{1}{2(u^2+1)^2} \right)  + C = $ 
    $ \tan(x/2) + 4\left(\frac{-1}{(\tan(x/2))^2+1} +\frac{1}{2((\tan(x/2))^2+1)^2} \right)  + C := F(x)$

$$F(\pi/2) - F(-\pi/2) = 2 $$
Wolfram tells that result ($=2$) is okay, but my integral is different from wolfram result: 
$$ \frac{1}{8} \sec \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(8 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-4 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-3 \cos \left(\frac{3 x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{5 x}{2}\right)\right) $$
Where I failed?

Comment: dont understand what you want to say ??? u did the integration!! then you didn't put the limits ? yes the answer is 2.... by substituing the limits.. what do you want ??

Comment: @learningstudent Keep calm. I said that my $F(x)$ is not equal to $F(x)$ from wolfram calculation

Comment: okay ... it may be due to some trigonometric transformations... so their can be many forms.,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no error in your solution. Both results (yours and Wolfram's) are equal up to a constant (which for an indefinite integral is arbitrary). You can check that using the equalities
$$ \cos (5\alpha) = \cos^5 \alpha - 10\cos^3\alpha \sin\alpha + 5\cos\alpha \sin^4\alpha = 16\cos^5\alpha -20\cos^3\alpha + 5\cos\alpha$$
$$ \cos (3\alpha) = \cos^3\alpha - 3\cos\alpha\sin^2\alpha = 4\cos^3\alpha -3\cos\alpha$$
$$ \frac{1}{\tan^2\alpha +1} = \cos^2\alpha$$
$$ \sec\alpha = \frac{1}{\cos\alpha}$$
Just write both results using only $\cos(\frac{x}{2})$ and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\frac{\sin^3x+1}{\cos{x}+1}=\frac{8\sin^3\frac{x}{2}\cos^3\frac{x}{2}+1}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=4\sin^3\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}.$$

Comment: Ok, it is another way to do that, moreover it is possible that it was a way of wolfram, but I still can't find bug in my solution and I am very interested in fix that.

Comment: fixing what ??? can you please tell us ? you already got the right answert as 2

Comment: @MrQuestion1999 The difference between yours and that of wolfram is $k-5/4$ which is constant so nothing is wrong.

Comment: @Coolwater how did you seen that the diff is $k-5/4$?